# how do I create an array in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").click(function() {
    $("#results").load("jquery-routing.php", 
       { pageNo: $(this).text(), sortBy: $("#sortBy").val()} 
    );
    return false;
  });
});
```

How do I create an array in jQuery and use that array instead of `{ pageNo: $(this).text(), sortBy: $("#sortBy").val()}`

Comment: Could you clarify? I don't think anyone really understood what you are trying to ask.

Comment: Jquery is not a language rather you should ask how to this in javascript.

Answer (score 141):

Some thoughts:

- jQuery is a JavaScript library, not a language. So, JavaScript arrays look something like this:

  ```
  var someNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  ```
- `{ pageNo: $(this).text(), sortBy: $("#sortBy").val()}` is a map of key to value. If you want an array of the keys or values, you can do something like this:

  ```
  var keys = [];
  var values = [];

  var object = { pageNo: $(this).text(), sortBy: $("#sortBy").val()};
  $.each(object, function(key, value) {
      keys.push(key);
      values.push(value);
  });
  ```
- objects in JavaScript are incredibly flexible. If you want to create an object `{foo: 1}`, all of the following work:

  ```
  var obj = {foo: 1};

  var obj = {};
  obj['foo'] = 1;

  var obj = {};
  obj.foo = 1;
  ```

To wrap up, do you want this?

```
var data = {};
// either way of changing data will work:
data.pageNo = $(this).text();
data['sortBy'] = $("#sortBy").val();

$("#results").load("jquery-routing.php", data);
```

Comment: thanks for all the help, I will make my next question simple,

How can I pass two variables to my jquery? I want to pass PageNo and SortBy ... 

<a href="routing.php?p=2&SortBy=error">2</a>

??

Comment: From what I understand: load(url, data) hits URL and sends data as the POST. If you wanted to hit routing.php?p=2&sortBy=error, you'd need to add that to the URL ("routing.php?p=" + pageNo + "&sortBy=" + sortBy). That, or make your PHP script read from $_POST or $_REQUEST instead of $_GET.

Comment: Seems here `var data = {};` need to change to `var data = [];`

Comment: Isnt jQuery a wrapper around javascript, and not a "plugin"?

Comment: Plugin is a weird word, yeah. I think I meant to say "library."

Answer (score 29):

You may be confusing Javascript arrays with PHP arrays. In PHP, arrays are very flexible. They can either be numerically indexed or associative, or even mixed.

```
array('Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Items 3')  // numerically indexed array
array('first' => 'Item 1', 'second' => 'Item 2')  // associative array
array('first' => 'Item 1', 'Item 2', 'third' => 'Item 3')
```

Other languages consider these two to be different things, Javascript being among them. An array in Javascript is always numerically indexed:

```
['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3']  // array (numerically indexed)
```

An "associative array", also called Hash or Map, technically an Object in Javascript*, works like this:

```
{ first : 'Item 1', second : 'Item 2' }  // object (a.k.a. "associative array")
```

They're not interchangeable. If you need "array keys", you need to use an object. If you don't, you make an array.

---

`*` Technically *everything* is an Object in Javascript, please put that aside for this argument. ;)

Comment: Malformed arrow function parameter list

Comment: Huh? It's not supposed to be Javascript, if you read attentively…

Answer (score 11):

Not completely clear what you mean.  Perhaps:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").click(function() {
    var params = {};
    params['pageNo'] = $(this).text();
    params['sortBy'] = $("#sortBy").val();
    $("#results").load( "jquery-routing.php", params );
    return false;
  });
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, but he's also coming from php, where arrays are also hashes...  In JavaScript, its not a 'hash' either - its just an object.  +1 - this was my interpretation of the question as well..

Comment: I know the difference between JavaScript arrays and objects.  However, it seemed like the real point of the question was to construct the parameters dynamically.

Answer (score 9):

Here is the clear working example:

```
//creating new array
var custom_arr1 = [];


//storing value in array
custom_arr1.push("test");
custom_arr1.push("test1");

alert(custom_arr1);
//output will be  test,test1
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been using jquery for a while but you might be looking for this:

[jQuery.makeArray(obj)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that I used.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      var array =  $.makeArray(document.getElementsByTagName(“p”));
      array.reverse(); 
      $(array).appendTo(document.body);
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

your question makes no sense. you are asking how to turn a hash into an array. **You cant**.

you can make a list of values, or make a list of keys, and neither of these have anything to do with jquery, this is pure javascript

Comment: ... in other words, an Array is an Array, a Hash is a Hash. Use whatever is appropriate for the situation, they're not interchangeable.